# Power BI Count/Sum Based on Multiple Columns

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I'm trying to count and sum based on multiple columns. When I tried the "group by" function in transform data, it gives me a timeout error.

Below is an illustrative example of what I'm trying to do. In the real dataset, the number of columns is 30+ and the number of possible entries in each column is also large, resulting in many unique combinations.

I'm not sure if there are other functionalities in Power BI that can achieve this, please send help!

Have this:
[image]

Want this:
[image]

Comment: Your example does not reproduce your problem. Simple group by Gender and Smoker, with Count and Sum(Salary) aggregations will easily produce what you show.  Please be more specific and provide an example and code that can reproduce your problem.

Comment: You are right it doesn't. Unfortunately, it's not practical to provide an exmple that would reproduce because it would be an enourmourse table and hard to illustrate what I want to do.                Imagine a much large database, column A has possible entries A1, A2, A3... A100, column B has possible entires B1, B2, B3... B100, column C has possible entires C1, C2, C3... C100. The list goes on to column Z. I need a similar count and sum for this database, I tried the "group by" function in power BI but it gave me a timeout error. Do you happen to know another approach that can achieve this?

Comment: Without a better understanding of what you are doing with at least some of those other columns, I cannot help you

Answer (score 1):

Im going to go ahead and guess that perhaps you want to sum all your columns without knowing how many of them you have, and this code can work on any number of columns, grouping the first two

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"Column1", "Column2"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", {"Column1", "Column2", "Attribute"}, {{"Count", each Table.RowCount(_), Int64.Type}, {"SUM", each List.Sum([Value]), type number}}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Grouped Rows", List.Distinct(#"Grouped Rows"[Attribute]), "Attribute", "SUM", List.Sum)
in   #"Pivoted Column"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Power Query, on the Tranform ribbon, click "Group By" and enter these settings.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the response. I tried this approach in both DirectQuery and Import mode but got timeout errors. I'm guessing it's because there are too many unique combinations from different columns. Do you know if there's another approach?

Comment: This approach is fairly standard. Without more info about your data, it is impossible to help further.